# sending notifications to selected multiple users

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

In my app I have a user hierarchy in form of a tree of users
A user can send a notification to all its subordinates, including indirect.

What is the best way to achieve this with Azure Notification Hub?

I see I can choose between either registration management from device or from backend.

Leaving aside the security, I don't see too much of a difference for my scenario. I guess the tag is the user id.

If 100 users need to receive a notification, I need to call 100 times to send the notification.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *in general* you are right - call 100 times. Do not use 'tag1 || tag2 ...' expression to reduce number of calls because it was originally designed for broadcast.

But for the *particular* case it is often possible to figure out much better way to implement the things based on some limitations (number of users, max hierarchy depth etc...) and other factors. So you could describe you application in more detailed way right here or contact Microsoft support or just email me directly or we even could setup phone or Skype meeting. What does work best for you?

Comment: OK, how to contact you

Comment: anefimov@microsoft.com